Unable to locate the program input point XXX in the dynamic link library mkl_sycl_dftd.4.dll

I use the complete example DFT located in the oneMKL local installation path.

\mkl\2024.0\share\doc\mkl\examples.

It will report an error near the end of compilation:

Unable to locate the program input point isMemoryObjectUsedByGraph@AccessorBaseHost@detail@_V1@sycl@@QEBA_NXZ in the dynamic link library mkl\2024.1\bin\mkl_sycl_dftd.4.dll


My linker uses oneMKL Link Line Advisor.The settings are as follows：
> mkl_sycl_dftd_dll.lib   
> mkl_intel_ilp64_dll.lib   
> mkl_sequential_dll.lib   
> mkl_core_dll.lib OpenCL.lib  


My environment:

CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1065G7 CPU;
GPU: Intel(R) Iris(R) Plus graphics card;
Operating system: Win11;
Integrated development environment: VS2022;
OneAPI basic toolkit: 2024.0.1.45;
OneMath kernel library: 2024.1.0.696;


I updated and repaired the Base package and OneMKL package, but the same error still occurred.
How to solve this error?



I have solved this error myself. The solution is as follows. I hope it can give some reference to friends who encounter similar errors:

My VS2022 environment settings VC++ directory-library directory set the compiler to version 2024.1, but I found that some other settings show links to version 2024.0. So I suspected whether there was a compiler file conflict. So I deleted the 2024.1 local compiler (basic package located in oneAPI) file and the program could run. After deleting 2024.0, the program cannot run. However, it should be deleted in 2024.1, and the program will not run.
So I suspected that after the oneAPI basic package was updated, the settings for the compilation part in VS2022 were not updated, or they stayed at the old settings, which caused this error. So I tried to modify the compiler settings in the settings, but some places do not support modification (it may be possible but I don't know). So I decided to uninstall and reinstall.
After I reinstalled the oneAPI basic package and VS2022, the error was no longer reported and was resolved successfully.

